# timer thread in c using SIGALRM

Tags: c, timer, pthreads, signals, alarm

I'm a newbie. I need to implement a timer thread in C. On timeout it must go to another thread/function to perform some activity. Can anyone help me for implementing it with SIGALRM? Would be good if anyone can leave some examples here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Go for `pthread_sigmask()`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_sigmask.html and `setitimer()`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getitimer.html

Comment: @kkuilla I dont need you to code for me.. I was only expecting someone to tell me if there's a way to do this. If yes, how that works. Thanks for your comments. I'll keep them in mind for any further discussions.

Comment: Alternatively there are the `timer_create` family of functions.  They are a bit more complicated than `itimer` but can more easily direct a signal at a particular thread or actually start a thread to perform a function when the timer goes off.

Answer (score 0):

dude ,i dont think anyone will be helping u,without u producing some codes..
anyhow as part of tutorial heres link
..read it..

pls

http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/getting_started/s1_timer.html

Comment: This would have suite better as comment.

Answer (score 0):

> `signal(SIGALRM, TR69_DM_SignalHandler);
>                   alarm(PassedFromCaller->TimeOut);
>                   pause();`

I found this working.. But is there any way I can avoid a pause statement??
I want my thread to continue with its work. Should I make the alarm alone in another thread?